# comparing a datagridview cell with an integer value

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

This coding was recently upgraded from C#.Net 2008 to C#.Net 2012. The value of this cell in this DataGridView = 4 but an exception is thrown every time my program arrives at this line. What am I missing here ?

```
if (((int)dgQueue.SelectedRows[0].Cells["StatusKey"].Value != 1 && isRequestCheck))
```

I'm receiving an InvalidCastException with a detail explanation of Specified cast is not valid...

Comment: Hav you tried `ToInt32(dgQueue.SelectedRows[0].Cells["StatusKey"].Value)`?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned `dgQueue.SelectedRows[0].Cells["StatusKey"].Value` should work with specified cast. Try to use below format and it should work, if the datatype of the value is equal to expected.

If the value expecting is 4 then the line should be

```
int i =(int)dgQueue.SelectedRows[0].Cells["StatusKey"].Value.ToString().Trim();
int i =Convert.ToInt32(dgQueue.SelectedRows[0].Cells["StatusKey"].Value.ToString().Trim());
```

Answer (score 0):

One second. Prior to the answers given (and thank you for those), I was able to make this work

```
if ((Convert.ToInt32(dgQueue.SelectedRows[0].Cells["StatusKey"].Value) != 1 && isRequestCheck))
```

Has (int) conversion been deprecated in 2012 ? Or, could there be a value other than an integer is the "StatusKey" cell collection (perhaps a null value) ? I'm trying to understand why this coding worked just fine in 2008 and now in 2012, it doesn't. Any ideas ??? I ask because this coding technique is all over this application and I'm thinking to change all my lines to the strategy above...